# How do you deal with Optional() in a string or any other value with Swift 2.0?

Tags: swift, option-type

I've tried looking at other StackOverflow inquires about this, I can't seem to find the solution to this. I'm not sure if this is due to me looking at threads which are non-Swift 2.0.

I will need NSNotification to pass any kind of value to my Main View Controller. But I keep getting:
`Optional(foobar)`

Here's a function on View Controller B:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    let notificationName = "CoreLocationNSN"
    let notification = NSNotification(name: notificationName, object: self, userInfo: ["doge":"foobar"])
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotification(notification)
}
```

Here's my main View Controller's initialization function:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "testNSNWithObject:", name: CoreLocationNSN, object: nil)
}

func testNSNWithObject(notification: NSNotification) {
    print("Printing...")
    print(String(notification.userInfo!["doge"]))
    print(String(notification.userInfo?["doge"]))
    print(notification.userInfo!["doge"])
    print(notification.userInfo?["doge"])
}
```

But, here's my output:

```
Printing...
Optional(foobar)
Optional(foobar)
Optional(foobar)
Optional(foobar)
```

Answer (score 3):

You just need to unwrap the `String`

```
func testNSNWithObject(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let dodge = notification.userInfo?["dodge"] as? String {
        print(dodge)
    }
}
```

> I suggest you to avoid the force unwrap operator `!` since it's dangerous and there are several safer solutions available in Swift.

Comment: @MattAndrzejczuk: Swift 2.1.1

Answer (score -1):

I've solved it, looks like it can be unwrapped by adding ! at the end, for some reason I thought my compiler was yelling at me for doing so:

```
func testNSNWithObject(notification: NSNotification) {
    print("Printing...")
    print(String(notification.userInfo!["doge"]))
    print(String(notification.userInfo?["doge"]))
    print(notification.userInfo!["doge"]!) // <<-- THIS ONE WORKED!
    print(notification.userInfo?["doge"]!)
}
```

Just going to keep this here since this issue has been troublesome for me in the past and the syntax seems very strange.

Does anyone know what else I could have done instead that would've removed the "Optional()" from the string?